# position: fixed is not working on iPad?

Tags: ios, css, ipad, css-position

I have added `position: fixed` and tried `position: sticky` and `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` etc and still position fixed not working.
I have fixed div into bottom of screen.

Is there anything I can do to make it work?
or is there a JS/jQuery plugin which can do so?

Comment: Can you replicate your problem in a code snippet ?